# x company pages remote which allow remote - say that again?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When you **Allow Remote** on **search companies** within jobs the text right above the search results looks odd.  It reads as such:

> x company pages **remote which allow remote**

[image]

Comment: you took the effort to add red arrows but no freehand circles? ... cute font tho.

Comment: Downvoted.  The text should be freehanded as well.

Comment: @brandaemon honestly, if you don't draw the whole page freehand from memory, why are you even posting it on meta?

Comment: @brandaemon Lies! There is no downvote on this post. :P

Comment: @Siguza They are freehand downvotes.

Comment: I despise free hand circles as mine are too perfect.  I would be blamed for using photoshop or snag it.

Comment: Those are remote pages which allow remote. Understand?

Comment: @Siguza [how I meta](http://imgur.com/a/I43Bn)

Comment: I have to be that guy: What font is that?

Comment: Try from the normal search page. You are on the search which allow search page.

Comment: @poke - its called Kristen ITC it's very friendly :-).

Comment: Yo dawg I heard you like remote so I put a remote in the copy so you can remote while you remote! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good spot! Fix just pushed to prod.